# Mahapps - How to set Proper Case in Titles

Tags: .net, wpf, mahapps.metro

I am using Mahapps and I am not able to set Proper case for  Window titles and Group box titles etc..

I tried googling and Typography settings.

If someone knows out there could you please help-me here..

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## New versions:

### Window Title

```xml
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
  TitleCharacterCasing="Normal" />
```

### GroupBox

Set a style (option 1) or set a property (option 2)

```xml
<!-- Option 1 -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroGroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="Controls:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing" Value="Normal" />
</Style>
```

```xml
<!-- Option 2 -->
<GroupBox Controls:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing="Normal" />
```

*Credits: [@Suplanus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39974356/3079753) & [@Oscar Vicente Perez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36077417/3079753)*

---

## Old versions:

### To set window title case:

Set the `TitleCaps` property on your `MetroWindow` to `false`.

```xml
<controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  TitleCaps="False" />
```

### To use title case in groupbox:

Put that `TextBlock` in the `GroupBox`'s header.

```xml
<GroupBox>
  <GroupBox.Header>
    <TextBlock Text="My Group Box"/>
  </GroupBox.Header>
  Some content
</GroupBox>
```

Comment: In MahApps 2, replace {StaticResource MetroGroupBox} with {StaticResource MahApps.Styles.GroupBox}

Answer (score 18):

`TitleCaps="False"` is obsolete, use this code in the Window:

```
TitleCharacterCasing="Normal"
```

Answer (score 13):

*Completing @Marcos answer:*

### There are better options than change the Header directly, without losing the Style and Bindings

I had the same problem 2 years after so i'll post my solution. I had to read the code at Git Hub so i realized that the MetroGroupBox Style uses a DependencyProperty in ControlsHelper class named 'ContentCharacterCasing' so we have 2 options, set an style or set the property directly in the control. But before, you need this xmlns in the xaml:

```
'xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"'
```

### Style Option:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroGroupBox}">
    <Setter Property="Controls:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing" Value="Normal" />
</Style>
```

### Control Property Option:

```
<GroupBox Margin="20,20,20,0" Grid.Row="0" Header="Cliente" Controls:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing="Normal" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case just adding `TitleCharacterCasing="Normal"` to `<controls:MetroWindow>` wasn't enough, and I had to also change this in the window properties (under miscellaneous).